# I'm having issues opening a file with notepad when i install a vb.net app on another system

Tags: vb.net

Whenever I run this code on my system, i get the desired output but when i deploy it on another system, it cannot find the file:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe", "C:\Users\AWESU PC\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Vector Group\Vector Group\Resources\YNd1.txt")
```

I figured out the file path was the problem and now I'm trying to use the root directory to call the file but still to no avail and it doesn't run on my system anymore.

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe", "Vector Group\Condition Files\YNyn1.txt")
```

Comment: is vector group a sub directory of your application directory?

Comment: Yes it is. It is also the name of the application

Comment: Use [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), setting its `.FileName` (notpad.exe) and `.Arguments` (your file path) properties. Then call `Process.Start()`. Of course, that file path must be a valid one. Try not to hard-code file paths. Define a known location in the directory structure where your executable is installed/created, find it at run-time and use this reference to build a fully-qualified path to the file you want to open.

Comment: @Jimi please could you give me a sample code snippet that explains this? Would really appreciate it.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some considerations.
You have these two references:

```
'Design time
"C:\Users\AWESU PC\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Vector Group\Vector Group\Resources\YNd1.txt"

'Published assembly
"Vector Group\Condition Files\YNyn1.txt"
```

The main problem here, is that you are referencing two different paths under undefined circumstances (code-related). This means that your paths are hard-coded, and this implies that you have to manually change those references when those conditions change. This is a really error-prone operation.

Your application should rely on the same Path structure when in Design-Time and when published, so that may you have your assembly access its resources without acrobatic twists or manual editing.

So, given that your published assembly path will be something like:

```
[Program Files]\[YourApplicationMainPath]\[YourAssemblyName].exe
```

your to-be-opened file being:

```
[Program Files]\[YourApplicationMainPath]\Condition Files\YNyn1.txt
```

Your Design-Time Path structure should reflect this:

```
[YourProjectPath]\bin\Debug\Condition Files\YNd1.txt
```

The `Resources` directory should only be used as a repository for your Design-Time resources (some of which will probably be included in your assembly) and not as run-time source.

That being said, you could instruct your Process this way:
(this path will be a valid one for both the VS Debug\Release run-time and the Published executable)

```
OpenFileWithNotepad("Condition Files\YNyn1.txt")
```

> I'm using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` because I don't know
>   whether your executable could be run by another executable or not.

```
Public Sub OpenFileWithNotepad(FilePartialPath As String)
    Dim MyAssemblyPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
    Dim psInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()

    psInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    psInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe"
    psInfo.Arguments = Path.Combine(MyAssemblyPath, FilePartialPath)
    psInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

    Dim _Process As New Process() With {
        .StartInfo = psInfo,
        .SynchronizingObject = Me
    }
    _Process.Start()
    _Process.WaitForExit()
    _Process.Dispose()
End Sub
```